# How to use Internal Set Theory to prove Nelson's axioms in "Radically Elementary Probability Theory"

Tags: logic, nonstandard-analysis

I'm currently reading through Nelson's "Radically Elementary Probability Theory". I don't believe Nelson gives a construction in that book, but Herzberg makes the claim that the axioms form a subsystem of IST.

Here's the question: how exactly do the axioms of IST imply the axioms used in REPT?

In particular, I'm struggling to prove the sequence principle and external induction. I'm currently working through Nelson's 1977 paper on Internal Set Theory, but it's unclear to me whether the results proved there actually specialize to the axioms in REPT.

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to Math.SE!

I'm not sure how the sequence principle goes and I don't have the means to check it right now, so answering that will have to wait (if somebody else gets here first, don't wait for me, go for it!). But you can prove external induction as follows:

Take a formula $\varphi$ in the language of Internal Set Theory (possibly with non-standard parameters). Assume that $\forall^{s} n. \varphi(n) \rightarrow \varphi(n+1)$ holds. Our goal then is to show that $\varphi(y)$ holds for all standard $y \in \mathbb{N}$.

First, use the axiom of Standardization to construct a set $P=\{x \in \mathbb{N} \mid \varphi(x)\}^{S}$ whose standard elements all satisfy $\varphi(x)$. We know from the axiom that this particular $P$ is a standard set.

Notice that for any standard $x$, we have $\varphi(x) \leftrightarrow x \in P$, and consequently $0 \in P$ and $\forall^{s} x. x \in P \rightarrow x + 1 \in P$ hold. Since $P$ is standard, Transfer applies to the latter and gives $\forall x. x \in P \rightarrow x+1 \in P$. But we know (from ordinary set theory) that there is only one subset of $\mathbb{N}$ which contains $0$ and is closed under successor: $\mathbb{N}$ itself. Consequently, $P = \mathbb{N}$. The desired conclusion, $\forall^{s} y. \varphi(y)$ follows immediately by noting that all numbers belong to $P$, and if $y \in P$ and $y$ is standard, then $y \in P \leftrightarrow \varphi(y)$.

Comment: Thanks so much! I have a follow-up question on the legality of transfer on $P$. I was initially concerned that since $P$ is defined by an external formula, we might run into issues with Transfer.
Is the reason we can do Transfer on $P$ because we can do Transfer to get 
$$\forall^{st} P (\forall x(x\in \mathbb{N} \rightarrow (x\in P \rightarrow x + 1\in P) ) \leftrightarrow  \forall^{st} x(x\in \mathbb{N} \rightarrow (x\in P \rightarrow x + 1\in P) )),$$
then specialize to any particular standard $P$?

Comment: Also, here's the statement of the Sequence Principle:
Let $A(n, x)$ be a (possibly external) formula. If for all standard $n\in \mathbb{N}$, there exists some $x$ such that $A(n, x)$ holds, then there exists a sequence (i.e. a function with domain $\mathbb{N}$) with $n \mapsto x_n$ such that $A(n, x_n)$ holds for all standard $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: The sentence $\forall^{s} Q. (\forall x. x \in Q \rightarrow x + 1 \in Q) \leftrightarrow (\forall^{s}. x \in Q \rightarrow x + 1 \in Q)$ is an instance of the Transfer axiom schema. Since $P$ is standard, he result follows. But alternatively, you could prove that "*the only standard set of natural numbers that contains $0$ and is closed under standard successors is $\mathbb{N}$*" as a lemma separately. This should also make it clear that which formulas were used to define $P$ acannot possibly make a difference here.

Comment: Got it. Would you happen to know how to use Idealization to prove the Sequence Principle as stated in the comment above?

Comment: Thanks for posting the definition. For internal $A$ that's straightforward, but I don't know how the general argument for external $A$ goes off the top of my head. I can give it some thought, but you're probably better off asking Mikhail Katz for details in the meantime.

Comment: IST does not prove the Sequence Principle, but BST does.

Comment: @MikhailKatz: Yeah, I suspected so. It's clear that if $\varphi$ is external, one has to use "galaxy-halo reasoning" or induction on the structure of $\varphi$ to establish this, and the former is precisely what happens in Kanovei-Reeken (Nelson's translation) - though I admit I don't yet have the proof written down even in the $\exists^s\forall^s$ case. I just skimmed REPT, and in all invocations of of this principle, the quantifiers are standard-bounded, so this means that at least _all instances actually invoked_ in the book should just be genuine theorems of IST.

Comment: The curious thing is that there isn't even a proof of the consistency (relative to ZFC) of IST+CC.

Comment: @MikhailKatz, I've read some more of Nelson's IST paper, and he shows (section 2) that every external formula with standard-bounded quantifiers can be reduced to an internal formula that is equivalent on all standard values of the free variables.

Comment: This seems to suggest that a slightly more precise statement of the Sequence Principle might follow from IST:
Let $A(n, x)$ be a (possibly external) formula with standard-bounded quantifiers (wlog a fixed std set). If for all standard $n\in\mathbb{N}$, there exists some $x$ (in the standard set) such that $A(n, x)$ holds, then there exists a sequence $n \mapsto x_n$ such that $A(n, x_n)$ holds for all standard $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I'm able to prove an altered statement where the $x$ guaranteed to exist is standard, but that seems to be a dramatic weakening of the principle. Here's the argument: By (S), we can form the std set $C$ of all $(n, x)$ satisfying $A(n, x)$, then by hypothesis, for all standard n there exists a standard x such that $(n, x)\in C$. By transfer, the same holds for all $(n, x)$. By Thm. 1.3 in the paper, there's a std sequence that does what we want.

Comment: The sticking point for me is that forming $C$ only guarantees that there's some $(n, x)\in C$ for all standard $n$ if we're guaranteed a standard $x_n$.

Answer (score 3):

Nelson's sequence principle or Axiom 5 (page 14 of REPT) is the axiom CC of of the theory SCOT, namely the following.

Let $\phi (u,v)$ be an st-$\in$-formula with arbitrary
parameters. Then $$ \forall^{st} n \in \mathbb N\; \exists x\; \phi(n,x)
\;\longrightarrow\; \exists f\, (f \text{is a function} \,\wedge\,
\forall^{st} n \in \mathbb N\; \phi(n, f(n)).  $$

This cannot be added conservatively over ZF but it can be added conservatively over ZF+ADC where ADC
is the axiom of dependent choice; see page 373 in

> Hrbacek, K.; Katz, M. "Effective infinitesimals in ℝ." Real Analysis
> Exchange 48 (2023), no. 2, 365-380.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how this axiom follows from Idealisation in ZFC + IST? In particular, how do you prove this result for external formulas?

The source you linked points to a claim that in IST, all external formulas are equivalent to internal ones with standard parameters, but it's unclear to me how this is proved or how it implies the Sequence Principle.

Comment: Where exactly does Herzberg claim this?  Does Nelson himself make such a claim anywhere?  @KellenBrosnahan

Comment: Herzberg makes this claim in "Stochastic Calculus with Infinitesimals", page 3 footnote 5:

"In his 1987 monograph on Radically elementary probability theory [60], Nelson proposes an axiom system which enlarges minIST by the following axiom scheme:


• (Sequence Principle) If $A(v_0, v_1)$ is any formula (which may involve the predicate “standard”) with the property that for all standard natural numbers n there exists some $x$ with $A(n,x)$, then there exists a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $A(n, x_n)$ holds for all standard $n$."

Comment: "The name is derived from Nelson’s [59] Internal Set Theory (IST), of which even Minimal Internal Set Theory combined with the Sequence Principle (see footnote 5 on p. 3) is only a small subsystem, see Sect. A.1 of Appendix A. Although Nelson [62] did not state this explicitly, an axiom system such as minIST is most probably what he had in mind when suggesting the use of “minimal nonstandard analysis” [62, p. 30]."

Comment: Nelson doesn't directly make this claim in REPT, as he only states the axiomatic system used within the text without referring to a broader system such as IST. The Sequence Principle as stated by Nelson is 
"Let $A(n,x)$ be a formula, internal or external. [...] If for all standard $n$ there is an $x$ such that $A(n,x)$, then there is a sequence $n\mapsto x_n$ such that for all standard $n$ we have $A(n, x_n)$." This is on page 14 of REPT.

Comment: @KellenBrosnahan, CC can be proved in BST (though apparently not in IST).  See Kanovei-Reeken, Theorem 3.2.3.

Comment: @MikhailKatz: A minor clarification: I should point out that Kanovei-Reeken refers to the book "Nonstandard Analysis, Axiomatically", and not the Kanovei-Reeken article which introduced BST.

Comment: @KellenBrosnahan, note that I am talking about the book.